# pass a data from a react component to another component which are on different routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `CountryList` react component

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BsSearch } from "react-icons/bs";

export default function CountryList({
  countries,
}: {
  countries: any;
}): JSX.Element {
  const [filter, setFilter] = React.useState("");
  const [sortType, setSortType] = React.useState("");

  console.log(filter);

  const sorted = countries.sort((a: { name: string }, b: { name: any }) => {
    const isReversed = sortType === "asc" ? 1 : -1;
    return isReversed * a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

  const onSort = (sortType: React.SetStateAction<string>) => {
    console.log("changed");
    setSortType(sortType);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          marginBottom: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <div>List of countries</div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <div style={{ position: "relative", marginRight: "1rem" }}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Filter"
              name="namePrefix"
              style={{ padding: "0.35rem" }}
              onChange={(e: any) => {
                setFilter(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "5px", right: "5px" }}>
              <BsSearch size="16" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={{ width: "8rem" }}>
            <div className="btn-group">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn dropdown-toggle sort-button"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                {sortType === "asc"
                  ? "Ascending"
                  : sortType === "desc"
                  ? "Descending"
                  : "Select"}
              </button>
              <ul className="dropdown-menu sort-button">
                <li>
                  <button
                    className="dropdown-item"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => onSort("asc")}
                  >
                    Ascending
                  </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button
                    className="dropdown-item"
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => onSort("desc")}
                  >
                    Descending
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="country-list-items">
        {countries &&
          sorted.map((item: any, index: number) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <Link style={{ display: "block" }} to={`/regions`}>
                {item.name}
              </Link>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ marginTop: "20px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        {countries && countries.length > 10 ? (
          <button className="secondary-button">Load More</button>
        ) : (
          <p>There are no more countries</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now from this component I need to pass the data of selected country id while the user clicks on the `Link` of the respective country, which I will be able to get by `{item.code}`. Also on clicking the `Link` the user will be redirected to `/regions` route where the list of regions of the selected country from this component will be shown. This is the `RegionList` Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { BsSearch } from "react-icons/bs";

export default function RegionList(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div style={{ marginTop: "3rem" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "space-between",
          marginBottom: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <div>List of regions</div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
          <div style={{ position: "relative", marginRight: "1rem" }}>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Filter"
              style={{ padding: "0.35rem" }}
            />
            <div style={{ position: "absolute", top: "5px", right: "5px" }}>
              <BsSearch size="16" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={{ width: "8rem" }}>
            <select name="sort" id="sort">
              <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
              <option value="desc">Descending</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="country-list-items">
        <div>
          <Link style={{ display: "block" }} to={`/cities`}>
            Alaska
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ marginTop: "20px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <button className="secondary-button">Load More</button>

        <p>There are no more countries</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to pass the country id from the `CountryList` component to this `RegionList` component because I will do a GET network call in the `RegionList` component using the selected country id passed from the `CountryList` component. But I am not able to pass the country id data from `CountryList` component to `RegionList` component as they are on different routes and they do not have any common parent component. This is the route file for Countries

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import CountryComponent from "../components/CountryComponent";

export class CountryRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<CountryComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}
```

here `<CountryComponent />` is the mother component of `CountryList`

This is the route file for Regions:

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";
import RegionComponent from "../components/RegionComponent";

export class RegionsRoute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<RegionComponent />} />
      </Routes>
    );
  }
}
```

here `<RegionComponent />` is the mother component of `RegionList`

Here is the Main Component where all the components are called

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "styled-components/macro";
import { CountryRoute } from "../country/route";
import { RegionsRoute } from "../region/route";
import { CitiesRoute } from "../cities/route";

const MainContainer = styled.div`
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 5rem;
`;

export const Main = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <>
      <>
        <MainContainer>
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <b>GEO SOFTWARE</b>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <Routes>
                <Route path={"/countries*"} element={<CountryRoute />} />
                <Route path={"/regions*"} element={<RegionsRoute />} />
                <Route path={"/cities*"} element={<CitiesRoute />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ToastContainer
            toastClassName={"toastContainer e-12"}
            hideProgressBar
            position="bottom-left"
            closeButton={false}
            autoClose={5000}
            bodyClassName={"toastBody"}
          />
        </MainContainer>
      </>
    </>
  );
};
```

Now how can I pass the selected country code data from `CountryList` to the `RegionList` component.

Comment: A shared context would be the way to go here

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Query Params for this. In the **CountryList** you can use the Link like this:

```
<Link style={{ display: "block" }} to={`/regions?country=COUNTRY_ID`}>
```

Then in the **RegionsList** youn can get that Query Parameter from the url and use as you want.

Check this example https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a simple "store" to keep track of the selected country independently of your component hierarchy.

### The simplest possible store

A stripped down, simplest implementation possible might look something like this:

```js
const data = {}

export default {
  setCountry: c => data.country = c,
  getCountry: () => data.country
}
```

Because the "store" data is a singleton, any component that imports the store will get the same info, regardless of where it is in the component tree.

```js
import store from './store';

export default () => (
  <div>{store.getCountry()}</div>
)
```

---

### Listening for changes, etc.

The example above omits some details that may be important, depending on what you're doing, like updating views that have already rendered when the country value changes.

If you need that sort of thing you could make the store an [event emitter](https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-emitter) so your components can listen for updates:

```js
import Emitter from 'events';

class CountryStore extends Emitter {
  data = {}

  getCountry () {
    return this.data.country;
  }

  setCountry (c) {
    this.data.country = c;
    this.emit('change'); // notify interested parties of the change
  }
}

export default new CountryStore();
```

With the emitter in place, components can register for change notifications when they mount:

```js
import store from './store';

function SomeComponent () {
  useEffect(() => {
    store.on('change', () => {
      // do stuff when store changes happen
    }, [])
  })

  return (<div>...</div>)
}
```

### Custom Hook

To make it easy to do this wherever its needed you could wrap it all up in a custom hook that handles it all and returns the current value and a setter `[country, setCountry]` just like useState would:

```js
const useCountry = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(store.getCountry());
  const handler = () => setCountry(store.getCountry());
  useEffect(() => {
    store.on('change', handler);
    return () => store.off('change', handler);
  })
  
  return [country, c => store.setCountry(c)];
}
```

Then your components have it easy:

```js
import useCountry from './useCountry.js';

export default function SomeComponent () {
  const [country, setCountry] = useCountry();
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current Country: {country}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setCountry(Math.random())}>Change Country</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

There are off-the-shelf libraries that will do all of this and more for you, but I thought it might be more helpful to explain an actual rudimentary implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have some sort of global state `country_id` which is initially equal to `null`.

When user clicks on a country, set that `country_id` to be equal to the clicked country id.

Now, Inside you RegionList component you can access the country id through `country_id` state.

You can achieve the state management by different ways:

1. Prop drilling
2. Context API
3. Use Redux or Recoil to handle state-management

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this is 100% what context is for.

It looks like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

const MyCountryContext = createContext(null);

export const useCountry = () => useContext(MyCountryContext);

export const MyCountryContext = ({children}) => {
    const [country,setCountry] = useState();
    return (
       <MyCountryContext.Provider value={[country,setCountry]}>
         {children}
       </MyCountryContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Use it like this:

```
export const Main = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <MyCountryContext>
        ...rest of your tree
    </MyCountryContext>
  );
}
```

Then, in any components that are below `MyCountryContext` you can use the hook just like `useState`:

```
import { useCountry } from './MyCountryContext';

const MyComponentThatUsesCountry = () => {
   const [country,setCountry] = useCountry();

   return (...)
}
```